# Ruby Class error output

Tags: ruby

[image]

can anyone tell me why the last line of my code output nothing? THX

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of text, post the text itself instead.

Comment: ok,I am sorry,I will use the code form text next time

Comment: If you give the code, people can directly use your code for testing, otherwise they have to type your code for checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `initialize` not `init` method,

```
class Mystuff
  def initialize
    @apple="I am instance"
  end

  def talk
    puts 'I am taking'
  end

  attr_reader :apple
end

thing = Mystuff.new
thing.talk
puts thing.apple
```

output

```
I am taking
I am instance
```

Comment: so,if I want to generate object from the class,we all need the initialize right?

Comment: That depends upon your need whether to initialize or not, but to initialize you need to use `initialize` not `init`.